# The second order accuracy of TR-BDF2 method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The following method is called the TR-BDF2:
$$U^* = U^n+\frac k4(f(U^n)+f(U^{*}))$$
$$U^{n+1}= \frac 13(4U^* - U^n+kf(U^{n+1})).$$
Apparently, this one-step method is second-order accurate while being a one-step method. But I am stuck on proving the said second-order accuracy using Taylor expansion. The issue is that when I write the local truncation error, I get the following: 
$$\tau_{n+1} = \frac 1k(3u(t_{n+1}) - 4u^*+u(t_n)) - f(u(t_{n+1})) = -\dfrac{k}{96}u'''(t_n)-\frac {k^2} {12}u'''(t_n).$$
This means that I am dealing with the implicit, trapezoidal method step incorrectly. Basically, what should $u^*$ be in this case? If it is exactly $u(t_{n+\frac{1}{2}})$, then there is no point even doing the implicit first step in the first place.

I would appreciate if someone makes this issue clear to me.

**EDIT**: So the only issue I am having is I do not know how to make sense of $U^*.$ That is, if there was $U^{n+0.5}$ instead, then everything is simple because I can expand $u(t_{n+1}), u(t_{n+0.5})$ all in Taylor expansion around the point $t = t_n$ and so establishing the desired order of accuracy is merely a task of some algebra. If this was the case, then the local truncation error will read as: 
$$\tau_{n+1} = \frac 1k(3u(t_{n+1}) - 4u(t_{n+0.5})+u(t_n)) - f(u(t_{n+1}))$$
and this is very simple to work with. So to sum up, my issue is what do I replace $U^*$ in the local truncation error?

Comment: What is $k$? Is it the time step?

Comment: @Ian, yes $k$ is the time step.

Comment: It looks like it is really a two-step method to me, you write $U^{n+1}$ in terms of $U^n$ and $U^*$ which is some kind of "$U^{n+\alpha}$" for $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Comment: that's what I thought too. But somehow it's referred as one-step method in literature. I am more concerned about proving the said 2nd order accuracy.

Comment: @Ian: It's a two-*stage*, one-*step* method. A two-step method (such as BDF2 by itself) would use both $U^{n-1}$ and $U^n$ for computing $U^{n+1}$.

Comment: Could you add some of your intermediate results? It seems strange that you get the same derivative with different powers of $k$, there could be some problem in unpacking the local error of the first stage while inserting in the second stage. For instance, inserting the first into the second stage one may get $U_{n+1}-U_n=\frac k3(f(U_n)+f(U_*)+f(U_{n+1}))$ which is composite trapezoidal up to the error in $U_*$ to $U_{n+1/2}$.

Comment: @Lutzl I edited my post if it makes more sense now.

Comment: Treat the first stage as an instance of the trapezoidal rule, and compute the error in $U^*$ with respect to $u(t_{n+1/2})$. Then plug it into the second stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the difference in the first stage as $U^*=U^n+\frac{k}2V$. Then
\begin{align}
V&=\frac12\left[f(U^n)+f\Bigl(U^n+\frac{k}2V\Bigr)\right]\\
&=f(U^n)+\frac{k}4f'(U^n)V+\frac{k^2}{16}f''(U^n)V^2+O(k^3)
\end{align}
which can be solved to third order as
\begin{align}
V&=f(U^n)+\frac{k}4f'(U^n)\left[f(U^n)+\frac{k}4f'(U^n)V+O(k^2)\right]
+\frac{k^2}{16}f''(U^n)\left[f(U^n)+O(k)\right]^2+O(k^3)
\\
&=f(U^n)+\frac{k}4f'(U^n)f(U^n)+\frac{k^2}{16}f'(U^n)^2f(U^n)+\frac{k^2}{16}f''(U^n)f(U^n)^2+O(k^3)
\end{align}
On the other hand,
\begin{align}
U^{n+1/2}&=U^n+\frac{k}2f(U^n)+\frac{k^2}8f'(U^n)f(U^n)+\frac{k^3}{48}[f''(U^n)f(U^n)^2+f'(U^n)^2f(U^n)]+O(k^4)  \\
&=U^*-\frac{k^3}{96}[f''(U^n)f(U^n)^2+f'(U^n)^2f(U^n)]+O(k^4)
\end{align}
so that on any exact solution one gets $U^*=u(t_n+\frac k2)+\frac{k^3}{96}u'''(t_n)$.

This should then contribute a second degree term, not a first degree term, in the error formula for the second stage.

Comment: ah, I see it now. Thanks!